# Nvidia graphics fllicker on 8200MG laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, screen, flicker

New to this forum but have had Ubuntu for a few months now. I wrecked my first install after trying to fix the screen flicker problem. I had the login where there was a choice of several desktops, only one of them was flicker free and I managed to mess up something else on that. 
In the end, trying any of the nvidia drivers caused the machine to crash (with broken up screen image) before I could change back the driver.

My new install is having the same problem - this time I just have the one desktop (the normal Ubuntu one) and sometimes the screen doesn't flicker for quite a while - it's definitely when the machine is working harder ie youtube etc.
Once  again I tried the nvidia driver - with the same disaterous results! I just managed to change it back otherwise I'd be on my third install now.

Can anyone help? I don't want to give up on Ubuntu but...

Comment: Also - since trying the nvidia driver, my software centre wont work anymore!

Comment: Oh and the system keeps reporting errors now - and sudo apt get wont work... maybe I need to somehow purge the nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the driver directly from the Nvidia website the results can be quite horribly broken.

if this is how you installed the driver follow the following steps:

1. Remove all Nvidia drivers with: `sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*`
2. Reboot the system
3. Use the Ubuntu Driver manager to install the recommended driver.

If that doesn't work for you or this is how you previously installed your driver then try the bumblebee project.

1. Google and Follow instructions for "Ubuntu $YourVersion Install Bumblebee"

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I appreciate it but I'm afraid my Ubuntu/linux knowledge is minimal - I've no idea how to "Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the E key." well I can prolly press the E Key but I don't know where I'm supposed to be. I have however fixed the fault with the updater not working by doing this "sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys [MISSING KEY] as I had an error message with a pub key number - I was surprised but it worked, so at least I'm just back to the flickering screen I think Ubuntu really doesn't like my computer

Comment: Also, in all previous instances I did get the drivers from the proper software installer, so all that is left is for me to try the bumblebee thing - I'll look into it and report back

Comment: just got bumblebee! It has cured the flickering - but unfortunately the whole machine is "running in slow motion" if that makes any sense? Maybe I can change some settings, it feels as if the computer is being overworked.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that the drivers don't work properly, completely remove them.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the `linux` line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
enter user name and password ... execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the NVIDIA drivers from Ubuntu repositories in a different way.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the `linux` line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
enter user name and password ... execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
sudo reboot
```

Comment: sorry I added my comments up above - new to this. I got bumblebee and the flickering is gone - trouble is the whole computer is "running in slow motion" now. I think it feels over worked. One other thing - on booting I get a message something like "APCI CCI drivers not installed" or something like that - the same as when I tried the normal nvidia drivers

Comment: thanks for the help so far - maybe my machine has had it!

Comment: @JohnyLondon : You have to remove the bumblebee software as well - I updated the answer - please repeat the complete procedure. When the computer boots to desktop and the system works, you can ignore this message - I have a similar one on my older DELL machine from 2007 with GT 8600M as well.

Comment: I'm confused - surely if I remove the bumblebee drivers... well I'll have no drivers or be back to the Ubuntu one that flickers? And surely if I purge nvidia then reload it from within the ubuntu manager I'll just have the nvidia drivers that screw things up really bad? Could it a ctually be a hardware fault in the machine? It used to have Vista but it got terribly slow, hence why I tried Ubuntu. With the Ubuntu graphics driver (that flickers) things are slow but acceptably so - with the bumblebee well its as bad or worse than the old Vista days.

Comment: thanks for the help though - I appreciate it!

Comment: @JohnyLondon : bumblebee is not a driver, it is a solution to switch between intel and NVIDIA graphics for newer chips with Optimus and meanwhile was replaced by nvidia-prime. But your NVIDIA card is not supported. Please try the solution and follow exactly the instructions. In case it does not work properly - yes, maybe it is a hardware problem ... :)